# How can I install adobe flash on the android emulator

Tags: android, flash, android-emulator

I want to use Adobe Flash in the development of Android applications. But how do I install flash on the emulator so that I can test my software with flash?

Comment: I followed the steps in [this entry at Extreme Tech](http://www.extremetech.com/article2/0,2845,2366195,00.asp) and worked perfectly! It's to install Market, but I think the idea still aplies. =)

Comment: other step-by-step to install market (and so install any app): http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21862/how-to-enable-the-android-market-in-the-google-android-emulator/

Answer (score 4):

To install the AIR runtime on the emulator:

adb -e install -r Runtime_Emulator_Froyo_20100930.apk

from this site:
http://flashsimulations.com/2010/10/19/developing-android-applications-with-adobe-air/

Comment: i downloaded the runtime from here: http://code.google.com/p/gt-cs4261/downloads/detail?name=Runtime_Emulator_Froyo_20100930.apk

Answer (score 0):

download the adodeflash player file(.apk) and install using the command adb install filename /sdcard/

Answer (score 0):

I tried this using comadobeflashplayer-1.apk, but it crashes the emulator browser. I was able to uninstall thanks to this helpful link:

http://forum.androidcentral.com/lg-optimus-s/43187-installing-flash-10-1-optimus-s.html

I did not put it on the sdcard (which is the -s option)

There might be some configuration option for the avd that allows it to run, but that's speculation.

Answer (score 0):

Install flash procedure for AVD

1. Download appropriate flash apk file from : http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html#flash_player_archives
2. Make sure yours PATH environment includes path to /SDK/platforms-tools (or wherever your adb program is)
3. Then open commandline (terminal or cmd.exe), and run following command

adb install FLASH.APK

This install flash APK to android virtual machine (as any other APK application package)

But let me warn you, FLASH does not work in webView, and I tried all answers from this portal.

Answer (score -1):

In the Android browser, browse to http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer and it should redirect you to the Android Flash install.

Comment: That creates a whole new pain, see http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/21862/how-to-enable-the-android-market-in-the-google-android-emulator/