# how to run the .swf file in android emulator?

Tags: android, flash

i have an swf file in local assets folder i have written the code like

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Context mContext= PanchangamActivity.this;

     WebView wv=new WebView(mContext);
     wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
     wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     wv.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
     wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
     wv.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/swf2.html");
 }
```

SWF2.HTML:

```
 <html>
   <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
  <object width="215" height="140">
    <param name="movie" value="flash.swh">
      <embed src="c:\Users\janardhan\Desktop\flash.swf"
           width="215" height="140">
      </embed>
  </object>
</body>
```

now while running that in android emulator i am getting[image]

please help me! how to solve this

Comment: did you try [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530313/not-display-swf-file-in-webview)?

Comment: sorry even this code is also show the same error!

Comment: are we have to install any download any swf plugins for android emulator to play swf files

Answer (score 2):

What you see is the missing plugin icon, you don't have the Flash Player installed.

I would recommend reading [How can I install adobe flash on the android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712623/how-can-i-install-adobe-flash-on-the-android-emulator) for information on how to get Flash up and running on the emulator.

Comment: i have tried to install the adobe_flash_player.apk  using adb through the command prompt it said success but after restarting the emulator same screen appeared

Comment: If that doesn't work, the only thing I can think of is to enable android market on the emulator and download the Flash plugin.

Comment: i am unable to upload or install any .apk file from to the emulator even after i reinstalled the emulator

Answer (score -1):

Maybe is just a typo you put here, not in your code, but...

```
<param name="movie" value="flash.swh">
```

instead of

```
<param name="movie" value="flash.swf">
```

could create some conflicts. 
And seen you are using

```
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

I suggest to embed Flash using SWFobject
http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/